# Iotivity 1.58 scons build failed for IOS

Tags: ios, scons, iotivity

My build environment:

```
OS:OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
```

Scons version :

```
v2.5.1.rel_2.5.1:3735:9dc6cee5c168[MODIFIED],
```

> boost framework copy to ~/Desktop/iotivity-1.2.1/extlibs/boost/ios/framework

build cmd:

```
scons TARGET_OS=ios TARGET_ARCH=arm64
```

build errors:

> scons: Reading SConscript files ... 
>   NameError: name    'bIn' is not defined:
>   File    `/Users/John/Desktop/iotivity-1.2.1/SConstruct`, line 28:    SConscript('build_common/SConscript')
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.5.1/libexec/scons-local/SCons/Script/SConscript.py",    line 604:    return method(*args, **kw)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.5.1/libexec/scons-local/SCons/Script/SConscript.py",    line 541:    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.5.1/libexec/scons-local/SCons/Script/SConscript.py",    line 250:    exec *file* in call_stack[-1].globals
>   File "/Users/John/Desktop/iotivity-1.2.1/build_common/SConscript", line    426:    env.SConscript(target_os + '/SConscript')
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.5.1/libexec/scons-local/SCons/Script/SConscript.py",    line 541:    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.5.1/libexec/scons-local/SCons/Script/SConscript.py",    line 250:    exec *file* in call_stack[-1].globals
>   File "/Users/John/Desktop/iotivity-1.2.1/build_common/ios/SConscript",    line 8:    env.SConscript('../darwin/SConscript')
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.5.1/libexec/scons-local/SCons/Script/SConscript.py",    line 541:    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.5.1/libexec/scons-local/SCons/Script/SConscript.py",    line 250:    exec *file* in call_stack[-1].globals
>   File "/Users/John/Desktop/iotivity-1.2.1/build_common/darwin/SConscript",    line 29:    elif bIn:

Comment: @XJOHN do format your post

Comment: OK, is it clear now?

Comment: @MeerDeen Thanks for formation.

Answer (score 0):

The code sequence looks buggy to me, in that you can percolate through the if statement chain ending up at the failing line without ever setting bIn.  Might be worth filing a bug on this one.

File mirrored here:

https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity/blob/1.2-rel/build_common/darwin/SConscript